# Rename 'subprocess' tag to 'python-subprocess'

Tags: feature-request, retag-request

Currently [subprocess](/questions/tagged/subprocess) refers to the [Python subprocess module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html). However this is too generic word to be used in this context. It should be [python-subprocess](/questions/tagged/python-subprocess) instead, following the syntax of similar tags like [python-multithreading](/questions/tagged/python-multithreading).

Comment: Not all do. 1,180 tagged subprocess, only 1,065 tagged with python _and_ subprocess. Search for `[subprocess]` and `[python][subprocess]` to see. This would need some manual love, it couldn't be done in one swoop.

Comment: @TimPost I can go through all these 115 questions and add a new tag [python-subprocess] when appropriate. After this the rest should be retagged from [subprocess] to [python-subprocess]. Does it sound right? Also could you point some questions on meta with discussion regarding tagging with [x-y] instead of tagging with [x] and [y]?

Comment: @TimPost Actually couldn't you filter all questions tagged ([python] or [python-2.x] or [python-2.5] or [python-2.6] or [python-2.7] or [python-3.x] or [python-3.1] or [python-3.2] or [python-3.3]) and [subprocess] and change tag [subprocess] to [python-subprocess]?

Comment: @TimPost After this, contents of the wiki page of [subprocess] tag need to be moved to the wiki page of [python-subprocess] and [python-subprocess-module] -> [subprocess] synonym should be changed to [python-subprocess-module] -> [python-subprocess].

Comment: I disagree with your approach.  The python-module-specific questions should be retagged, then the tag wiki should be corrected.

Comment: @Charles *The python-module-specific questions should be retagged, then the tag wiki should be corrected*. That's what I proposed so I don't understand what you disagree with.

Comment: @TimPost Are you there?

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost Yes, sorry I've been a bit busy. I'm waiting to see a consensus here. If positive, I think I can clean it up pretty quickly. (I tweeted a link to this in hopes of getting a few more people to chime in).

Comment: @TimPost Could you please retag these questions?

Comment: @TimPost Tim, could you please take care of this?

Answer (score 2):

By looking at [questions tagged `subprocess` but not `python`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/subprocess+-python) I guess the answer is fairly obviously yes... so long as [subprocess](/questions/tagged/subprocess)[python](/questions/tagged/python) *is* consistently used to mean the Python `subprocess` module, and not just about spawning child processes.

Comment: It appears one can't search for `[python][subprocess]-module` which would reveal questions likely not concerning `subprocess` module. Having said that I think a) they are very few, b) retagging them to the proposed `python-subprocess` tag won't harm them much if at all.